# Regex for checking if a string should not contain certain words but those words are ok if they have a 'to' or 'for' preceeding the words

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, regex-negation

I have a use case where for a given string, I need to check that the string does not contains words like '*com*', '*dot*' etc but it is ok to have these words if they are like this- '*for com*' '*to com*' '*to dot*'. Struggling to write the regex/ javascript function for this.

Eg:

```
'maincom', 'maindot'
```

should not be acceptable as per regex pattern

```
'main for com', 'main for dot', 'main to dot', 'main to com'
```

should be acceptable as per regex pattern

Answer based on Jan's comment below-

```
^(?!.*\b(?:for com|to com|for dot|to dot)\b).+
```

Comment: You should consider adding some example string to your question and explain which string should pass and which ones should not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
^(?!.*\b(?:com|dot)\b).+
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/pLwrQz/1/).

Comment: Thanks, this works great. I just need to tweak it to allow on 'to com' , 'to dot', 'for dot' and 'for com' in string and not other strings. Let me try that. Would be great if you can help me with that too.

Comment: Ok, i think i just needed to append the to and for in front of each words matched here. ^(?!.*\b(?:for com|to com|for dot|to dot)\b).+

Comment: Jan  - can you help me with the opposite regex too? I need to match any words that have 'for com','to com', 'for dot', 'to dot' but not words which have just com or dot without preceding 'for' or 'to'

Answer (score 1):

What pops into my mind is not a single regex but a short algorithm:  split the string into "words" (separated by one-or-more non-alphanum characters), producing an array of values.  See if the offending words occur in the array, and if so, peek at the preceding word in each case to see if it is "to."

While it might well be *possible* to devise a regex, I think that it would be difficult to debug it and thence to maintain it. (And, let's face it ... "they'll change their mind and want something slightly different.") I daresay that my suggested approach would be "plenty fast enough" and more maintainable.